# [ibm][db2][jcc][t4][2055][11259] Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error

Tags: java, db2, websphere

I am calling Stored procedure from java based web-application using DB2 as database and WebSphere as server.

Most of the time SP gets executed properly but sometimes it gives following exception:

```
[ibm][db2][jcc][t4][2055][11259] Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation.
The command requested could not be completed because of a permanent error condition detected at the target system.
```

Db2jcc Driver version :
**IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture 3.1.157 [  v9.1 FP0 (GA)  ]**

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will match your scenario, but it looks like there is a known fix for an error with the same message as the one you reported

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ07622

which recommends moving up to DB2 V9.5 fixpack 5.